Termux copy paste problem
I started today coding with termux on mobile, I want to git clone but I can't copy paste the link to my github, I tried to do CTRL + ALT + V but it doesn't work
It would be very nice if someone could help me.

I just found out, we need to hold in the terminal screen and then click paste when it pops up
